# In a dataframe, how to replace (harmonize) values such as "Not applicable", "Not avilable" , "Unknown" , all with just "NA"?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am working on a df with 1000s columns (some column contains numeric values, some contains character, and some logical) and my df conatins values such as "Not applicable", "unknown" , "not determined" etc. How do I to replace all these values just with "NA" ?

1. I have tried following code and it outputs empty cells rather than replacing with "NA".
   **na_string <- c("NA", "Not_Applicable", "[Not Available]", "[Not Applicable]" , "[Unknown]", "[Not Evaluated]").

   df%>% replace_with_na_all(condition =~.x %in% na_string)**
2. I have also used naniar package **df %>% replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% common_na_strings)**
3. I have also tried to replace them one at a time using  **df <- mutate_all(df, funs(replace(., .=="[Not Available]", NA)))**   or also have used **df[df == "Not Available"] <- NA** and tried this as well ** **df %>%
   mutate_if(is.character, list(~na_if(., "Not Available")))****

Either I am getting empty cells in place of those values or it will not replace anything at all. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `across` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
na_string <- c("NA", "Not_Applicable", "[Not Available]", "[Not Applicable]",
               "[Unknown]","[Not Evaluated]")

df <- df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., .%in% na_string, NA)))
```

Or if you have an older version of `dplyr` you can use `mutate_all` :

```
df <- df %>% mutate_all(~replace(., .%in% na_string, NA))
```

---

In base R, you can try :

```
df[sapply(df, `%in%`, na_string)] <- NA
```

Note that values in `na_string` need to exactly match with what you have in your data. So `"Not Available"` is different than `"[Not Available]"`.

Comment: df <- df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., .%in% na_string, NA)))    worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We could change it to `NA` while reading the datasset with `na.strings` and this doesn't involve any external packages.  It is better to do the changes while reading itself rather than changing it afterwards

```
df <- read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = na_string)
```

---

If we want to change it to `NA` after reading

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, x %in% na_string, NA))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(., . %in% na_string)))
```

Comment: df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, x %in% na_string, NA))  worked for me . Thanks very much.